# Wanhao duplicator i3 print bed support warped

Tags: heated-bed

As you can see in the picture, my heated bed support is too low on the right side, even touching the Y-axis chassis end plate.

[image: The front of the printer, from where you can see the heated bed support leaning down on the right, even touching the Y-axis chassis.]

This is only the case on the front of the printer. The back is perfectly straight. Do you know how this can happen and what can be done?

Comment: Has it always been warped, or has it only happened recently? How old is the printer? What material is the heated bed support made from? Acrylic, MDF, Aluminium, Steel?

Comment: It was not warped as I know and it's getting more and more to the point that it starts to hit the chassis on the front. The printer is exactly 1 year old and the heat bed support is made of aluminium.

Comment: I just checked mine.  It's only 2 weeks old and it has this same problem.  It's not hitting, but it is bent like this.

Comment: I sort of fixed it by adding another linear ball-bearing and bearing-holder to the y-axis on the position where the support bent down. This works without screws because the support presses down at that point.

Answer (score 2):

okay, after ferociously dismantling the whole bed I found out that the bed and the bed support are perfectly straight!
So there is something  warping the bed and support. De Y-axis bars are perfectly flat too.

I found out that my table is not flat! This made the complete printer warped and even bent the print bed. put some cardboard under the frontleft foot and presto! As flat as it should be!